# PowerShell CheckedListBox only select one option at a time

Tags: forms, powershell, checklistbox

I Have a PowerShell form that contains a `'System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox'` object. Currently I am able to select more than one checkbox option at a time:

[image: CheckedListBox with 2 selected]

Is there a easy way of making the `CheckedListBox` only allow one selection?

[image: CheckedListBox with 1 selected]

or will I have to use some `'onClick'` event logic within my script?

**CheckListBox Proteries:**

```
$checkedlistbox2.BackColor = 'Control'
$checkedlistbox2.BorderStyle = 'None'
$checkedlistbox2.CheckOnClick = $True
$checkedlistbox2.ColumnWidth = 56
$checkedlistbox2.FormattingEnabled = $True
[void]$checkedlistbox2.Items.Add("W2K")
[void]$checkedlistbox2.Items.Add("WXP")
[void]$checkedlistbox2.Items.Add("WS7")
$checkedlistbox2.Location = '107, 284'
$checkedlistbox2.MultiColumn = $True
$checkedlistbox2.Name = "checkedlistbox2"
$checkedlistbox2.SelectionMode = 'None'
$checkedlistbox2.Size = '192, 15'
$checkedlistbox2.TabIndex = 66
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing the SelectionMode attribute to "One"?

```
$checkedlistbox2.SelectionMode = "One"
```

Alternatively, you could use a radio button control, which allows only one selection at a time? Something like this:

```
$radioButton1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$radioButton2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$radioButton1.Checked = $True
$radioButton1.Name = "W2K"
$radioButton1.Text = "W2K"
$radioButton1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
$radioButton2.Name = "WXP"
$radioButton2.Text = "WXP"
$radioButton2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,30)
$form.Panel1.Controls.Add($radioButton1)
$form.Panel1.Controls.Add($radioButton2)
```

Comment: I have tried the `SelectionMode = "One"` but this does not work. The radio buttons are nice idea. Do you know how to set up two sets of radio button groups within the same form (both only allowing one selection)?

Comment: RadioButtons in the same parent are automatically grouped. So if you place the two groups into two different Panel containers, that'll work. There's also the GroupBox control, but that draws a border around the groups.
`$groupBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox`